# How do I prove these facts regarding the proof of a lemma related to partitions of unity regarding local finiteness of a collection?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Consider:

**Lemma $1.4.$** Each topological manifold is locally compact.

**Proposition $1.5.$**  Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space that satisfies the second countability axiom. Then there is a sequence of compact subsets  of $X:  (K_j )^\infty_{j=1}$ such that

• $K_j \subseteq K^{\text int}_{j+1} , \forall j$ ;

• $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty K_j=X$.

**Lemma $1.6.$** Let $U \subseteq M$ open, and $A \subseteq U $closed. Then there's a smooth function $ f : M \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ so that

• $\operatorname {supp(f )} \subseteq U$ ;

• $ f(p) > 1/2 , \space \forall p \space \in A$.

Proof: Because of Lemma 1.4, we can apply Proposition 1.5 to $M$. Let
$(K_j )^\infty_{j=1}$ be as in that proposition. If $j ≤ 0$, then we call $K_j:= \emptyset$. Thenfor all $j$ the set

$U_j := U \cap (K^{\text int}_{j+1} \setminus K_{j−2})$   is open

and

$A_j := A \cap (K_j \ \setminus K^{\text int}_{j-1}) \subseteq U_j$ is compact

Let $f_j$ be as in the statement of our lemma  applied to $U_j$ and $A_j$ . Call $U_0 := M \setminus A,$ and $f_0 = 0$. Then

$\{U_j ; j = 0, 1, . . .\} \text{is a locally finite covering of }M \tag 1$

So there is a well-defined smooth function $f$ on $M$ like that for all $p\in M$, $$f(p)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} f_j (p)$$

The support of each function $f_j $ lies in $U$, so does the support of $f$

$\text{If } p \in A, \text{ then there is a  }j ≥ 1 \text{ such that } p \in A_j\tag 2$

It follows that $f (p) ≥ f_j (p) > 1/2$

I am trying to prove (1) and (2). I know the definition of locally finite is that a collection $C$ of subsets of $M$ is locally finite if for every $p\in M $ has a neighborhood that intersects at most finitely many of the sets in $C$. I am clueless about how to even start. I don't see how it was useful to define $U_j$ like that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding (1), the sets $U_j$ and $U_k$ are disjoint for $k\geq j+3$, since $U_k\subseteq M\backslash K_{k-2}\subseteq M\backslash K_{j+1}$ and $U_j\subseteq K_{j+1}$.

Therefore $U_j$ can only intersect $U_{j-2}$, $U_{j-1}$, $U_{j+1}$ and $U_{j+2}$, and potentially $U_0:=M\backslash A$, so the covering has multiplicity at most $6$. Moreover, the sets cover $U$, since if $p\in U$ then you can let $j$ be the first index for which $p\in K_{j+1}^{\text{int}}$, and then certainly $$p\notin K_{j}^{\text{int}}\supseteq K_{j-1}\supseteq K_{j-2},$$
so $p\in U_j$.
Since $U_0=M\backslash A\supseteq M\backslash U$, the sets cover all of $M$.

In particular, each point $p\in M$ has a neighborhood intersecting at most $6$ members of the cover (namely, take one of the $U_i$'s containing $p$ as that neighborhood).

As for (2), for $p\in A$,  if $j$ is the first index where $p\in K_j$ then certainly $p\notin K^{\text{int}}_{j-1}$, otherwise $j$ would not be the first such index. Therefore we get $p\in A_j$.

Comment: what is "multiplicity" of a cover? Is it a definition or just your own words?

Comment: @darkside It's pretty standard, just means every point is in at most $5$ members of the cover.

Comment: In the proof in my post, why do they take: $U_0:=M\setminus A$? Doesn't that contradict the definition $U_j := U \cap (K^{\text int}_{j+1} \setminus K_{j−2})$? Because for $j=0$, I have $U_0=U \cap (K^{\text int}_{1} \setminus K_{−2})=U \cap (K^{\text int}_{1} \setminus \emptyset)=U \cap K^{\text int}_{1}$ So the $U_0$ was already defined like this.

Comment: Would $K^{\text int}_{j+1}\setminus K_{j-1}$ work as a a neighborhood intersecting 5 of the elements?

Comment: @darkside that does look a little bit like an oversight about $U_0$, maybe their indices are off by $1$.  As for your other question, it would work, since it is contained in the $U_i$'s and every element is in one of those sets, but once you know the $U_i$'s themselves have multiplicity $5$ that is already enough, you don't need to do anything further.

Comment: Assuming that is the second one that was intended $U_0= M\setminus A $ why would that be more useful in the problem than the other one, I don't see it used anywhere

Comment: @darkside  the author needs to make sure he is covering the entire space $M$. (So technically I should have said multiplicity of cover is at most $6$.  (I think you can actually do better than $6$ for the multiplicity, by the way, but it’s not important enough to worry about.)

Comment: What did you meant with "since if $j$ is the first index where $p\in K_j$ then certainly $p\notin K^{\text{int}}_{j-1}$" I don't undertand why that is true  and how is that related to the fact that  the sets  $K_j \backslash K^{\text{int}}_{j-1}$ cover $M$

Comment: @darkside its because, like I said, "otherwise $j$ would not be the first such index."  If $p\in K_{j-1}^{\text{int}}$ then $p\in K_{j-1}$, so $j-1$ would be an earlier index.  And the point is, this means $p\in K_j$ and $p\notin K_{j-1}^{\text{int}}$, so $p\in K_j\backslash K_{j-1}^{\text{int}}$.  This works for arbitrary $p$, so the sets cover. (I should have also added this shows they cover $A$, so then including $M\backslash A$ gives you a cover of $M$.  I'll update that.)

Comment: Shouldn't we also show that the Uj's cover U(How?) in order to argue that for any point p is in one of them and therefore its neighborhood intersects at most 5 of them

Comment: I am thinking that to prove the $U_j$'s cover $U$, I can just argue that the sice the $A_j$'s cover A and $A_j \subseteq U_j$, also the $U_j$'s cover A, ans since $A_0=M\setminus A$, actually thetìy cover M, what do you think?

Comment: @darkside I'm not sure chat is working, so I'll just post this here:  I updated the answer.
It's basically the same idea as the proof that the sets $A_j$ cover $A$.  You could also, if you wanted, argue the way you have argued.

Comment: Since you've taken $k\geq j+3$, shouldn 't be that $U_j$ can only intersect $U_{j-3}$,$U_{j-2}$, $U_{j-1}$, $U_{j+1}$ and $U_{j+2}$,$U_{j+3}$, ? And when could it be that it intersects $U_0$ but not any of these others?

Comment: Here, I am manually posting the chat link since it won't do it automatically.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148949/discussion-between-m-w-and-darkside