# In the proof of $\bigcup_{j=1}^n K_j=\bigcup_{j=1}^n K_j \setminus K^{\text int}_{j+1} $ , does induction allows to pass to $n=\infty$?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, set-theory, induction, smooth-manifolds

Consider:
the question that I asked here  [How do I prove these facts regarding the proof of a lemma related to partitions of unity regarding local finiteness of a collection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780717/how-to-prove-that-the-following-collection-of-set-is-locally-finite/4780934?noredirect=1#comment10161220_4780934)

In this case I just focusing in the following:
Given that

• $K_j \subseteq K^{\text int}_{j+1} , \forall j$ ;

• $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty K_j=M$.

• If $j ≤ 0$, then we call $K_j:= \emptyset$

I am trying to prove explicitly that $M=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty K_j=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty K_j \setminus K^{\text int}_{j+1} $I was trying to do it by induction, but then I realized that what I was doing is  only induction up to a certain step, but that the conclusion does not follow from induction.

$$\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty K_j\setminus K_{j-1}^{\text int}
= K_1\setminus K_{0}^{\text int}\cup K_2\setminus K_{1}^{\text int} \cup ...$$
$$= K_1\setminus\emptyset \cup K_2\setminus K_{1}^{\text int} \cup ...$$
$$= K_1 \cup( K_2 \cap (K_{1}^{\text int})^C )\cup ...$$
$$= K_1 \cup (K_2 \cap \overline{(K_{1}^C)}) \cup ...$$
$$= [(K_1 \cup K_2)\cap (K_1 \cup \overline{(K_{1}^C)}))] \cup...$$
$$= [(K_1 \cup K_2)\cap (\overline{K_1} \cup \overline{(K_{1}^C)}))] \cup...$$
$$= [(K_1 \cup K_2)\cap (\overline{K_1 \cup (K_{1}^C)})] \cup...$$
$$=[(K_1 \cup K_2)\cap (\overline{M})] \cup...$$
$$=[(K_1 \cup K_2)\cap M] \cup...$$
$$=[(K_1 \cup K_2)] \cup...$$
This is actually induction, I know I should have written the basis step and then the inductive step separately, but I realized after I had typed it all, sorry.

So  this is induction corresponding to proving that:

$\bigcup_{j=1}^n K_j\setminus K_{j-1}^{\text int}=\bigcup_{j=1}^n K_j $

but I wanted to prove that

$\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty K_j\setminus K_{j-1}^{\text int}=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty K_j $ and I don't think induction allows me to do this passage to the limit, does it? If yes, why?If not, how do I justify it then?

Additionaly, are the topological manipulations regarding the interior, closure and complement correct? I have used that a compact set is closedm so it coincides with its closure, because we're in a manifolds, so it is Hausdorff, and that the closure of a union is the union of the closures

Comment: The question boils down to: if $\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j = \bigcup_{j=1}^n B_j$ for all $n$, is it true that $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty B_j$? The answer is yes, and while I don't think it follows from induction, it's quite easy to prove directly.

Comment: @GregMartin Could you please show how?, what doesn't follow from induction proving the passage to n? or proving the initial equality?

Comment: I recommend thinking about my comment (for more than two minutes) as an isolated exercise; I bet you'll be able to answer your questions yourself.

Comment: Induction does not generally allow passage to the limit; for example, consider the statement "for every $n,$ $\sum\limits_1^n 2^i$ is finite" (which is true and can be proved by induction), yet no passage to the limit is allowed. On the other hand, when you are considering an infinite union, if you can show by induction that $\bigcup\limits_1^n A_n = \bigcup\limits_1^n B_n,$ then you can conclude that the union of all of the $A_i$ equals the union of all of the $B_j$....

Comment: ...but the reason of this falls in the definition of union, $x \in \bigcup\limits_1^\infty A_i \iff x \in \bigcup\limits_1^n A_i$ for some $n.$ So, in this case, because an infinite union reduces to some finite union, by definition, you can do induction. But in general you cannot pass to the limit with induction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $x \in M$, then $x$ must be in one of the $K_n$. As the collection $\{K_1, K_2, ..., K_n \}$ is finite, we can find the minimum $m$ such that $x \in K_m$ and $x \notin K_{m-1}$ (by convenience, assume $K_0 = \emptyset$). Therefore, $x \in K_{m} \setminus K_{m-1} \subseteq K_{m} \setminus K_{m-1}^{int}$

Comment: This is true and is perfectly satisfactory to argue this way.  It is maybe worth noting that the fact that every natural number is finite does, originally, have to be proved by induction or well-ordering.   However, as this is a well-known fact, my answer was a little obtuse and I've deleted it.

Comment: Yes, the existence of smallest $m$ is a consequence of well-ordering principle